# Brits addressing police as 'Detective <surname>' - is there a name for this (trope)?

Tags: trope, crime

I first noticed this decades ago in the BBC series *Silent Witness*, and since then repeatedly, and most recently in *The Devil's Hour* (Amazon). British characters involved in a police investigation, usually as witnesses, victims, or their families, etc, address non-uniformed police as e.g. 'Detective Jones'. This despite the fact that *Brits don't do this*. Other police will either use just first names or surnames, often with the abbreviated rank (e.g. 'DI (Detective Inspector) Burnside', 'DS (Detective Sergeant) Mukerjee', etc. Civilians tend to follow suit, although the (real) detective who investigated a crime I was a witness to made me call him 'Jim'. I am supposing it's done to make the shows more palatable to an 'international' audience, although Jed Mercurio's *Line of Duty* doesn't do it, and it has sold well outside the UK. Is there a name for this type of doctoring of dialogue - is it a trope?

Comment: If it's not just a mistake (e.g. the British filmmakers have never interacted with a detective, but have watched a lot of American cop movies), I'd call it "internationalization," but that term doesn't seem to be widely used in this context.

Comment: It reminds me of the 'TV Tropes' thing [Eagleland Osmosis](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EaglelandOsmosis) - e.g. 'Louis Ciccone: Your honour, may I approach the bench?
Judge: You've been watching too much American TV, Mr. Ciccone. No one "approaches the bench" in a Canadian court.'

Comment: I feel it's just poorly researched writing.  I'm not sure a *lot* of Brits are aware of the correct term to use - I'm aware of DI/DS/DC as terms but I wouldn't know that Detective was strictly incorrect.  My favorite cop movie Hot Fuzz does use DS/DC so I'm pleased to see that was accurate.

Comment: @iandotkelly - anyone who watched/watches _The Bill_ knows how to address a cop, I'd have thought?

Comment: It might be the case of a civilian not knowing how to correctly address a non-uniformed police officer, hence they use the universal (although Americanized) "detective". US tv shows have promoted this word so many people will use it

Comment: @iandotkelly The special features on the Hot Fuzz disc go into some detail about how the film gets some surprising things right about police work (and not by accident, either). It's a great movie, and the extras are good.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't know 'detective' was wrong until I researched further after reading this. I was, of course aware of the whole DCI/DI/DS/DC & generic 'officer' thing, but had never extrapolated to 'just detective' being wrong.

Comment: Who says "detective" is wrong? If you don't know their rank then what else are you going to call them? "officer" would be wrong because they're not police officers, they're police detectives.

Comment: @OrangeDog In the UK police, 'Detective' ranks are held by plain-clothed (non-uniformed) police officers. 'Officer' would be perfectly OK. "Career progression: Police Constable / Detective Constable - this is the starting rank for police officers" - Leicestershire Police.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Members of the public are quite likely to be unaware of the actual ranking system used internally by the police and instead think as OrangeDog does (officer = uniform, detective = plain clothes) – as evidenced by multiple Brits saying as much in the comments here. It’s also not clear what you’re asking about: Your example says “Detective Jones”, but who in the UK would ever say “Officer Jones” about a police officer? To me at least, the use of _officer_ is strictly limited to cases where the name is not included.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - The cop who investigated a crime that I and a number of others witnessed said to us 'I'm DC Jim Jones but you can call me Jim'. Many UK police dramas have featured accurate ranks for decades. Likewise news stories. 'Mr or Ms XXX' is common among people who don't know a police officer's rank but wish to be polite or formal.

Comment: Obviously, if the police officer actively instructs people, they’d be expected to follow that hint. But if he just presents himself as ‘DC Jim Jones’, you’ll get an array of variations back, quite naturally, and I’m quite confident that in real life Britain, some of those would be ‘Detective Jones’ – out of ignorance and influence from American TV shows, sure, but they would be there.